# How to get nth value for index and match when concatenating two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, search-indexing

I have this dataframe here, and am filtering in cell E1:
`=IFERROR(SORT($B$2:$B$6+$C$2:$C$6),"")`

[image]

I am trying to do an index and match based on the array to get the values in A and D. Ive managed to almost do that with the formula `=INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH($E1,$B$2:$B$6+$C$2:$C$6,0))`

However, it gives me two `Apples` values when i get to the date `1/12/2023 8:00`, when I would like to see both `Apples` and `Bananas`. How would I get the nth value given I am concatenating two columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a great solution as it uses Helper Column. Not extensively tested. Please check at your end.

[image]

E1 has your formula as it is.

In F1 put 1 then in F2 put the following formula and drag it down up to the intended rows.

```
=IF(E2=E1,F1+1,1)
```

This will sequentially number the duplicates. So we have 1 & 2 for [image]

In G1 the formula is

```
=IF(F1=1,INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH($E1,$B$2:$B$6+$C$2:$C$6,0)),INDEX(FILTER($A$2:$A$6,($B$2:$B$6+$C$2:$C$6)=E1),F1))
```

Drag it down up to the intended rows.
Now for the second matching date-time it will return the next applicable value.

Please test at your end.

SORT, FILTER etc are available in O365 & 2021.

**Edit 1**

You could now directly use the below formula in G1, no need of IF and your INDEX version

```
=INDEX(FILTER($A$2:$A$6,($B$2:$B$6+$C$2:$C$6)=E1),F1)
```

[image]

**Edit 2**

Solution without a Helper Column

G1

```
=INDEX(FILTER($A$2:$A$6,($B$2:$B$6+$C$2:$C$6)=E1),COUNTIF($E$1:E1,E1))
```

[image]